# Pointwise convergence of a function sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, limits

How to prove that the sequence of functions $(f_n)$, defined by
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}(n-1)x&\text{if $0\le x<\frac{1}{n}$}\\1-x&\text{if $\frac{1}{n}\le x\le 1$}\end{cases}
$$
converges pointwise?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i am trying to prove that the limit is 1-x but i don't manage to do that. Can you please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is almost correct. At $x=0$ the limit is $f(0) = 0$. You ask why? Well, what is $f_n(0)$?

Comment: $f_n(0)=0$ i don't see what do you mean

Comment: Right. You have $f_n(0) = 0$ for every $n$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(0) = 0$. Now choose some $x\in (0,1]$ (i.e., $x\in [0,1]$, but $x\neq 0$). Then is there an $N$ such that $\frac 1N < x$?

Comment: we can take $N=E(\frac{1}{x})+1$?

Comment: What is $E$? Why do you assume I know what you mean with this?

Comment: E(1,5)=1  the enteer part

Comment: 'enteer' is not an English word. So, I still don't understand.

Comment: But I assume you mean the floor function. Then you're right. There exists such an $N$. Then also $\frac 1n < x$ for all $n\ge N$, correct?

Comment: yes i don't see how to conclude

Comment: So, what is $f_n(x)$ for $x\ge N$?